# Finding background information on historical England & Wales electoral registers?

Tags: 19th-century, england, 20th-century, wales, voter-lists

Find My Past has recently added a collection of England and Wales Electoral Registers, the data set [England & Wales, Electoral Registers 1832-1932](http://search.findmypast.com/search-world-Records/england-and-wales-electoral-registers-1832-1932).

I would like to find background information about the registers, especially (but not exclusively) information that I can download and view off-line.  Find My Past has some resources in their "Learn More About These Records" section, but there may be times I am working with downloaded images and can't get back online to read their background information.

My end goal is to create checklists so I can query my genealogy database and generate lists of names to look for in the registers. I would like to have:

- a timeline of changes in the law and the eligibility requirements for voters
- a timeline of which years have only one register and which have Summer/Autumn
- any other information that helps me properly interpret the information in the registers I have collected already

I am less concerned with maps covering the individual constituencies because I can capture that information from [A Vision of Britain](http://www.visionofbritain.org.uk/).  Using the information found in the research guides, I hope to create checklists for each place I am searching for, showing what registers exist and where they can be found.

What websites, research guides, and finding aids have been the most help to you in your research?

Comment: When you say coverage table, do you mean coverage in terms of area (i.e. the streets covered), or dates covered, or something else?

Comment: Mostly I want a timeline of changes in the law, and changes in eligibility rules, plus notes on which years have spring/autumn registers instead of just one per year.  The data is in the BL guides, and I can extract it, but if someone has already done so, I'd rather build on prior work. Coverage in terms of parish varies by location, so if that data exists, I'll have to search the local Record Offices and FHS (family history societies), Genuki, etc.  I want to build a list of cutoff dates for the eligibility for each year so I can fine-tune the possible residence dates.

Comment: I've never seen anything more than those two BL Guides - as I was reading your first paragraphs, my mind was answering with those two Guides - then I found that you'd already located them. GenUKI can list the constituency in the page for each place, but not always. What I find much more problematic is understanding the property qualifications post-1832. Sometimes it seems contradictory but I think I may be missing selection criteria, such as what type of constituency.

Comment: I know I have a bad habit of half-answering questions as I write them, and I may break out the two BL guides and make a self-answered question.  I'd like to know more about the property qualifications -- basically anything that helps me evaluate the information I do locate.

Answer (score 1):

These two guides are available for download from the British Library:

- [Guide to electoral registers in the British Library (PDF format, 92KB)](http://www.bl.uk/reshelp/findhelprestype/offpubs/electreg/electoralregisters.pdf) (which when downloaded has a title of "UK electoral registers and their uses") and
- [Parliamentary Constituencies and their Registers since 1832](http://www.bl.uk/reshelp/findhelprestype/offpubs/electreg/parliamentary/parliamentaryconstituencies.pdf), also from the British Library, which was suggested and linked to by Find My Past in their "Useful Links and Resources" section.
- Information Leaflet No 10, [Electoral Registers at London Metropolitan Archives (63KB)](https://www.cityoflondon.gov.uk/things-to-do/london-metropolitan-archives/visitor-information/Documents/10-electoral-registers-at-london-metropolitan-archives.pdf)

These websites have been helpful so far:

- [A Vision of Britain Through Time](http://www.visionofbritain.org.uk/)
- TNA's research guidance on [Electoral Registration](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/electoral-registration/)
- http://www.electoralregisters.org.uk/